# How do you set bytes directly with DASM?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I'm learning 6502 assembly language, and having trouble working something out. I've been trying out a [JavaScript 6502 assembler/emulator](http://6502asm.com/), and noticed that most examples have a section that looks like:

```
colors:
  dcb 0,0,0,0,0,$9,$9,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

I've tried to Google what `dcb` means, and the closest I've got is decimal-coded binary. From looking at the source code, it looks like the assembler is taking the values and inserting each one as a separate byte at the current point in the code.

I'm using DASM locally to assemble my code, and it doesn't support `dcb`. Is there an equivalent way in DASM to set byte values directly in the code like this?

Comment: If you haven't yet found out what `dcb` stands for after posting your answer, the directive `DC` stands for Define Constant, and the `B` for byte.

Comment: Other common mnemomics for this in various assemblers were `.byt` or `.db` for data byte (in which case `.dw` would usually work for 16-bit values, i.e. data word).

Answer (score 1):

`.DC` works fine, but the direct equivalent in [DASM](http://dasm-dillon.sourceforge.net/) is

```
colors:
    dc.b 0,0,0,0,0,$9,$9,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

The `b` is for bytes, as AusCBloke said. You could replace it with `w` for words (2 bytes) or `l` for long words (4 bytes).

You have correctly surmised that the purpose of `dc.x` is to inject constant values at the current location.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as is often the way, asking the question helped me find the answer. According to [this page](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/scholar/dasm.html), `.DC` is used for this purpose.

So the example in the question would look like:

```
colors:
  .DC 0,0,0,0,0,$9,$9,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
```